# How to make my toddler stop crying every night?

Tags: toddler, sleep, crying

I have a 15-month-old daughter. Since birth, she has been crying every night around the same time with her eyes closed. I haven't had a real good sleep at night since she's been here. I've had numerous doctors' appointments to check on things and everything comes back normal. She's lactose intolerant and has a diet with no dairy. I wonder whether it's from what she's eating. How to make her stop crying?

Comment: It may be that people would find it useful to have some more detail, for instance, how long does the crying last? How often does your daughter cry? etc.

Comment: shes whining with her eyes close, could it be discomfort then?

Comment: She has a diet with no dairy.\

Comment: Its every night around the same time.

Comment: Does she seem to be asleep while crying?  Does she seem scared, seem in pain, or just fussy/needs comfort?  Does a specific thing help her stop crying and go back to sleep (backrub, drink of milk or water, etc)?

Comment: Is there something that fairly consistently happens in her environment around the time she starts with crying?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Parenting on SE!

I have a couple of ideas that may help with your current sleepless nights situation...

1. **White noise:** There are all sorts of types of white noise machines. We have one that does water, nature, ocean, rain, heartbeat, or plain ol' white noise. We also have a Munchkin that has white noise, music, a projector, night light, and more. These have been wonderful as to filter out any excess noise that may disrupt the child. Our child now sleeps beautifully with it, and as soon as we turn it off she wakes up.
2. **Humidifier:** Having a humidifier, especially in dryer climates, allows the child to breathe heavier and easier. Less coughing, congestion, or boogies helps for longer, deeper sleep.
3. **Feed before bedtime:** I have found that feeding before bedtime is a great way to get the child sleepy and also to sleep longer.
4. **Routine:** Create a bedtime routine. Do the same thing each night, keep bedtime the same time each night, and follow it every night. Kids crave structure and by allowing the child to know what to expect is a great way to ease anxiety and help the child feel more peaceful before bedtime.
5. **No napping close to bedtime:** You want your child to be tired and ready for bed when it's bedtime. Eliminate late naps, and follow the routine step above.

I hope this helps. I understand the struggle of no sleep and I wish you the best in finding a solid resolution!